# open policy agent - false vs none

Tags: cloud, open-policy-agent, rego

Trying to understand the concept of falsehood in OPA. My situation is such - I need to verify whether all cloud resources are in allowed regions of AWS. What I have right now is:

```
allowed_locations := ["eastus", "westus"]

exists(array, value) {
    array[_] == value
}

all_resources_in_allowed_regions {
    not any_resource_not_in_allowed_regions
}

any_resource_not_in_allowed_regions {
    some index
    exists(allowed_locations, input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index].values.location) != true
}
```

The problem is, I think I'm missing something about the result of policies/functions when it's not true - for instance, the result of `exists(allowed_locations, "westeurope")` is not false but "undefined" of some sort, which means that the result of `exists(allowed_locations, "westeurope") != true` is also "undefined", which means that all_resources_in_allowed_regions is assigned `not "undefined"` which is true.

How would you solve this issue with OPA? Am I missing something about the proper way to use it?

Comment: I've found some solution: define a `not_exists` function which is simply `not exists(array, value)`, then configure a policy of `any_resource_not_in_region { not_exists(allowed_locations, resource[_].region)}` and then `all_resources_in_region { not any_resource_not_in_region}`

Comment: The answer seems to be pretty good - please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "For All" section of the docs:

More explanation about what is happening: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#universal-quantification-for-all

Quick Examples: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#for-all

Following on from your reply [open policy agent - false vs none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62891905/open-policy-agent-false-vs-none#comment111217007_62891905) the updated policy as described looks like:

```
allowed_locations := ["eastus", "westus"]

exists(array, value) {
    array[_] == value
}

not_exists(array, value) {
    not exists(array, value)
}

all_resources_in_region {
    not any_resource_not_in_region
}

any_resource_not_in_region {
    not_exists(allowed_locations, input.planned_values.root_module.resource[_].values.location)
}
```

Playground example: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/f1bI2Ddc9D